# What happends when a call to `send` fails when there is pending data from calls to `send` with `MSG_MORE`?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, error-handling, udp

From `man 2 send`:

> MSG_MORE (since Linux 2.4.4)
>
> (…)
>
> Since Linux 2.6, this flag is also supported for UDP sockets, and informs the kernel to package all of the data sent in calls with this flag set into a single datagram which is transmitted only when a call is performed that does not specify this flag.

Fine enough. So when I: 1) Issue a few calls to `send()` with flag `MSG_MORE` specified; 2) Issue a call to `send()` without this flag specified and `send()` fails; 3) Issue one more call to `send()` –

**Will the data from calls (1) and (3) be joined in a single datagram?**

In other words: Does a failure of a call to `send()` count as a failure to append this part to the whole datagram, or does it count as a failure to send the whole datagram consisting of this call to `send()` and any previous calls to `send()` with `MSG_MORE`?

I hope for the latter, because I’m afraid otherwise error recovery in certain scenarios might be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The manpage misses a crucial piece of information: data "sent" on the step (2) are going into the same datagram which has been accumulated at the step (1). Only then an entire datagram is actually sent out. Regardless of this actual `send` success or failure, the datagram is gone, and (3) cannot possibly be joined with it.

Answer (score 0):

The `MSG_MORE` flag essentially means *append without sending, the caller has more data to send*.  Once a `datagram` is determined ready to actually send, *send()* is called without `MSG_MORE`, and the `datagram`, with all appends, is sent.  But if an error occurs, any datagram that has been growing `no longer exists.

```
char msgs[][20] = {"msg1", "message2","more messages", "yet another message"};

//scenario1 normal, no errors
send(s, msgs[0], strlen(msgs[0]+1,MSG_MORE);//datagram is started 
send(s, msgs[1], strlen(msgs[1]+1,MSG_MORE);//datagram is appended 
send(s, msgs[2], strlen(msgs[2]+1,MSG_MORE);//datagram is appended 
send(s, msgs[3], strlen(msgs[3]+1,0);//dategram is appended and sent 

//scenario2, with errors
send(s, msgs[0], strlen(msgs[0]+1,MSG_MORE);//datagram is started 
send(s, msgs[1], strlen(msgs[1]+1,0);//dategram is appended  and send
send(s, msgs[2], strlen(msgs[2]+1,MSG_MORE);//error occurs, datagram lost. 
send(s, msgs[3], strlen(msgs[3]+1,0);//dategram is sent, but only `msgs[3]` 

//scenario3 with errors at end
send(s, msgs[0], strlen(msgs[0]+1,MSG_MORE);//datagram is started 
send(s, msgs[1], strlen(msgs[1]+1,MSG_MORE);//datagram is appended
send(s, msgs[2], strlen(msgs[2]+1,MSG_MORE);//datagram is appended 
send(s, msgs[3], strlen(msgs[3]+1,0);//error occurs here, datagram lost.
```

This is the danger of tightrope walking without a net.  One possibility of a net would be to append messages to a buffer in parallel as you are calling your `send/MSG_MORE` commands.  Keep it around until you have a successful send of your `datagram`. If a failure, package up the buffer and resend it (without `MSG_MORE`).